# cbind runs very slow

Tags: r

I have a large data.frame jobs, this is what it looks like:

```
jobs[1,]
  submittime  starttime finishtime  cputime maxrmem  host
1 1367000999 1367000999 1367001001 0.017996      -1  i-sim-11-190
length(jobs$finishtime)
[1] 13280089
```

It's big, 11GB in memory.
Now I have a vector `cputimenorm`

```
length(cputimenorm)
[1] 13280089
```

So I wanted to add this vector as a column to jobs:

```
jjj <- cbind( jobs, cputimenorm )
```

And this is still running for 16 hours already on a powerful Proliant server with 400GB RAM.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried just doing `jobs$cputimenorm <- cputimenorm` ?

Comment: In addition to @SeñorO's comment: You should absolutely not use a data.frame with a size like that. Working with a data.frame copies the whole object far to often. Make it a data.table and do as many operations by reference as possible. PS: Having 400 GB RAM is nice, but it will help you only so far. You still need to write efficient code.

Comment: Roland, the data.frame that's what fetch() from database gives me. Should I convert it to data.table?   But why copying a 11G object should take over 16 hours?

Comment: Yes, make it a data.table. But make sure to study and understand the documentation of that package. Copying ones doesn't take that long ...

Comment: But maybe you should leave the data in the database and query the db directly?

Comment: Try doing `system.time(cbind(jobs[1:i,], cputime[1:i]))`, where you start `i` off small and see how computing time changes as it increases. That may help you get to the bottom of why it's taking so long.