# R cbind is very slow

Tags: r, performance, cbind

There is a question that has a very similar title ([cbind runs very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050900/cbind-runs-very-slow)) but it does not help me with my problem. I am retrieving 10+ JSON files with 100 variables each and I try to create one big data.frame/table with 1000 columns. In practice, I do not use the very same JSON-file as per the example but different ones. Ideally only the problematic line `cx <- cbind(cx, bx)` would speed up as the other lines (unlist, as.data.table) work well for me and I would not know what else to use. I know, "cbind is slow" but do I have any alternatives? Ideally with Base R.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

starttime <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:10) {          # loop through all  10 json files
  zz <- Sys.time()         # measuring the time for each loop
  urlx <- "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json"
  jsnx <- fromJSON(urlx)
  if(i==1) {
    ax <- unlist(jsnx)
    bx <- as.data.table(ax)
    cx <- bx
  }
  for (j in 1:100) {        # loop through all 100 variables in each file
    ax <- unlist(jsnx)
    bx <- as.data.table(ax)
    cx <- cbind(cx, bx) # <---- VERY SLOW ----
  }
  zz <- round(Sys.time()-zz,1)
  print(sprintf("%1.1f", zz))
  flush.console()
}
endtime  <- Sys.time()
endtime-starttime
```

This gets slower and slower with more files, here my timings.

```
[1] "0.7"
[1] "1.3"
[1] "1.3"
[1] "1.6"
[1] "2.1"
[1] "2.2"
[1] "2.5"
[1] "3.2"
[1] "3.4"
[1] "3.5"
```

Comment: the problem is progressively expanding your data.frame. If you instead create a list with the intermediary results you can use `do.call(cbind, result_list)` to perform only a single `cbind`. Eg. `result_list <- vector("list", n); result_list[[i]] <- [do stuff here]; do.call(cbind, result_list)`.

Comment: Alternatively: As you are using `data.table`, you can progressively add the columns using `cx[, c(column_names) := ax]`, which should be somewhat linear in time-complexity.

Comment: Are you sure your code is doing what you want it to? In particular the part where you're looping through all 100 variables? Looks to me you're just running the same code 100 times and the output looks non-sensical.

Comment: There are several packages with a `fromJSON` function. Please start your scripts with calls to `library(pkgname)` whenever you use non-base functions.

Comment: Related: [Dynamically _filling_ an object using a for loop is fine - what causes problems is when you dynamically _build_ an object using a for loop (e.g. using `cbind`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500364/loop-to-dynamically-fill-dataframe-r).

Comment: Added the library calls, thanks Rui Barradas. The code is nonsensical in this example as it is using the very same json-file and the same variable. In my actual code I do use different json-files and each time a different variable.